# terraform launching ec2 instance

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Can anyone help me out of this error?

**Code:**

```
 provider "aws" {
    access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    secret_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    region = "us-east-1"

}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance"

  ingress  {
   from_port = 8080
   to_port = 8080
   protocol = "tcp"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
    ami = "ami-40d28157"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"    
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]

    user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                echo "Hello, World" > index.html
                nohup busybox httpd -f -p 8080 &
                EOF               


  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"  
  }
}
```

This is the Error:

> aws_instance.example: Creating...
>
> Error: Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: 
>           status code: 403, request id: 3319f97b-c1e7-4259-8ed2-4ca7b5c7ce07
>
> on main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_instance" "example":
>      19: resource "aws_instance" "example" {

Comment: Are sure you have enough permission to launch an ec2. For the sake of testing , can you create a user with full permissions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this piece of code:

```sh
...
      + name                   = "terraform-example-instance"
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + vpc_id                 = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_security_group.instance: Creating...
aws_security_group.instance: Creation complete after 5s [id=sg-0aa4ba2483dca70ed]
aws_instance.example: Creating...
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
aws_instance.example: Creation complete after 42s [id=i-07604b706323de813]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

I have a couple of ideas why you're seeing this error:

- This is a new AWS account and the activation process haven't finished yet.
- Your AWS keys don't have enough permissions to launch EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the root cause of this issue is encoded and can be produced for a variety of reasons, e.g., an organization tag policy that prevents creating instances with missing tags or missing IAM permission.

If you have sufficient permissions, you may be able to decode the authorization using `aws kms decode-authorization-message --encoded-message EncodedMessageText`, which will usually reveal the exact cause of the issue.

Another strategy you may consider to help reduce the surface error of the issue (Terraform resource definition vs. IAM permission, etc.) is to use the AWS CLI to create the same resources (use the same access key/secret key), e.g.,

```sh
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-40d28157 --instance -type t2.micro --security-group-ids security-grp-id --user-data file://user-data.txt
```

I've found the AWS CLI to occasionally produce more clear error messages than the Terraform output. If it works via the AWS CLI and not via Terraform, it suggests some slight adjustment to your resource definition or how you provide credentials. If they both fail, its usually suggestive of missing permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem while creating EC2 but it was working fine in case of VPC creation.
Goto the user you have created for terraform from iamadmin then check the Policies .
I have found that "**AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2**" policy was Attached directly .
The description of the policy is :

Policy ARN
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2
Description
**Denies access to certain actions, applied by the AWS team in the event that an IAM user's credentials have been compromised or exposed publicly. Do NOT remove this policy. Instead, please follow the instructions specified in the support case created for you regarding this event.**

Answer (score -1):

If you are just starting with Terraform try to run using EC2FullAccess in IAM policy. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_region.html